# Traffic shaping for SSH

Tags: ubuntu, traffic-shaping

How can I set a bandwidth limit for a SSH connection in my lan with Ubuntu 16.04LTS?

I tried using wondershaper but it limits the entire interface.

Answer (score 0):

Put this into ~/.ssh/config where 100k is the limit for the connection.

Host server1
    Hostname server1-slow 
    Port 22
    proxycommand pv -q -L 100k | nc your.host.com 22

Comment: (0) welcome (1) use 'code' markdown (the {} button or select,ctrl+K) for 'typewriter' input and output especially where linebreaks and indentation matter as they do here (2) `pv` only handles data in one direction, `ssh` requires bidirectional (3) if you're going to hardcode the `nc` (instead of `%h %p`) setting `Hostname` and `Port` is unnecessary and misleading